# Integer point's Counter Clock Wise sorting

Tags: c++, geometry

Given four integer points of a quadrilateral,which can be anything of it's kind (like rhombus,rectangle,trapezium,parallelogram,square ,or normal quadrilateral) , how can I sort those points counter clock wise (without using atan2() function or any double point calculation) so that I don't end up with diagonals as sides of it ?

I have coded something like this as struct :

```
typedef struct {
      long long x,y ;
} point ;

vector<point> p ;
```

I can't figure out what will be compare function within the sort function to sort the points in CCW order without using any double point calculation.Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you do when the shape of the quadrilateral is ambiguous? See the last (bottom-right) example of this image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Six_Quadrilaterals.svg. Those four points can be used to draw a few different quadrilaterals, which may change your meaning of sorted.

Comment: You can not get around using fractional numbers in one or the other way. You can make your own implementation of exact fractions with a numerator and a denominator, but simply using floating point numbers is easier. You can not get around this because at some point in your algorithm, you will have to compare angles at which points are located to eachother. To calculate these angles, there is no way around fractional numbers. This leads to the question: Why do you want to avoid "double points"?

Comment: Just btw, tan(a) < tan(b) exactly when a < b, so you don't need to reverse tan for testing if a < b. You can test tan(a) < tan(b) and it is equivalent to a < b.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that (assuming your pivot is at 0, 0 ):

```
bool operator<(point other)
{
    // normalize both points
    if(y > 0 && other.y > 0)
        return x < other.x;
    else if(y < 0 && other.y < 0)
        return x > other.x;
    else
    {
        return y < other.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: For normalize point (brr... you mean vector from origin to point, right?) without "double point calculation" (see description), we need make length of two vectors the same, for example: first = (*this)*length(other)/gcd(length(*this), length(other)); second = other*length(first)/gcd(length(*this), length(other));

Comment: Try run your code on data { {1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {-1, -1} } I get result { {1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1} }, i.e. CW order, not CCW.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code (don't need normalize vectors, also assuming that pivot at (0,0)):

```
int Quadrant( const Point &pt ) {
    if( pt.x >= 0 && pt.y >= 0 )
        return 0;
    if( pt.x < 0 && pt.y >= 0 )
        return 1;
    if( pt.x < 0 && pt.y < 0 )
        return 2;
    if( pt.x >= 0 && pt.y < 0 )
        return 3;
}

std::sort( std::begin( pt ), std::end( pt ), []( const Point &lhs, const Point &rhs ) {
    return Quadrant(lhs) < Quadrant(rhs) || ( Quadrant(lhs) == Quadrant(rhs) && lhs.x*rhs.y - lhs.y*rhs.x > 0 );
    });
```

Points from different quadrants we compared by them quadrants, and to compare points in the same quadrants we find signum of dot product from vector from origin to second point and rotated by 90 degrees on CCW vector from origin to first point.